# Using dropdown component of bootstrap 3, I need to get a reference to selection as well as selected text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a dropdown to select an option and need to use the selection to control subsequent processing.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" >
    Select Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Handling Documents</li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Create Document from Form</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Create New Folder</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Rename Folder</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

I get the selected text ok in a click function

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var selected = $(this).text();
console.log('action '+selected); 
$('#main_action_text').text(selected);
});
```

I would like to have a reference number for the chosen action line to use in my javascript to avoid having to test for "Create Document.." etc. 
How is this best achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data attributes :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Handling Documents</li>
  <li role="presentation" data-action="1"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Create Document from Form</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" data-action="2"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Create New Folder</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" data-action="3"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Rename Folder</a></li>
</ul>
```

And with jQuery :

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var action = $(this).data('action');
  console.log('action : ' + action);
});
```